# Parent comment's author name

Tags: comments

[image]

I was really suprised when I couldn't find WP functionality to display the person's name who was replied to.. Any way around this problem? **How do I get the name of parent comment's author?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your *comment callback*, you could get that info with the help of the `comment_parent` property of the current `$comment` object.

We can then use the [`comment_author()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_author) function to display the comment author's name:

```
// Display the parent comment author's name:
if( $comment->comment_parent )
    comment_author( $comment->comment_parent );
```

and the [`comment_author_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_author_link) function to display the comment author's link:

```
// Display the parent comment author's link:
if( $comment->comment_parent )
    comment_author_link( $comment->comment_parent );
```

Comment: This should give the name of the author, one level above, so if someone replies to Rick, then it should output Rick @TwerkingN00b