# Parent comment's author display_name

Tags: comments

[Parent comment's author name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218824/parent-comments-author-name)

I found this code and would like to modify it as follows: if someone changes the display_name, the name in the comments should also change.
I was able to achieve this with the following code in the comments:

```
$usermeta = get_userdata($comment->user_id);

<?php echo $usermeta->display_name?>
```

However, I don't know how to change the code below to show display_name here as well.

```
if( $comment->comment_parent )
comment_author( $comment->comment_parent );
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You want to show the display_name for the parent comment instead of the author name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I got it!

```
if( $comment->comment_parent ) {
    $parent_ID = $comment->comment_parent;
    $parent_comment = get_comment($parent_ID);
    $parent_usermeta = get_userdata($parent_comment->user_id);
    echo $parent_usermeta->display_name; }
```

Answer (score 0):

So to do the same thing but for the parent comment this should do it. This is untested but does the same thing as your first case, but with the parent comment object instead of the current comment.

```
if( $comment->comment_parent ) {
    $parentComment = get_comment($comment->parent);
    $usermeta = get_userdata($parentComment->user_id);
    echo $usermeta->display_name ; 
}
```

Does that do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It does not show the name of the parent author, but the name of the child author.

I rewrote `$usermeta` to `$parent_usermeta` so they don't conflict... but unfortunately it's not good either...